# How to run js function using url?

Tags: jquery, url

Click on a div inside a menu on left side I load a specific file from `chapters`folder inside a div on the riht side.

```
<div id="menuLeft">
<div id="file01">File 01</div>
<div id="file02">File 02</div>
<div id="file03">File 03</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$("#menuLeft div").click(function () {
var id = "chapters/" + $(this).attr('id') + ".php";
$('#divRight').load(id);
});
```

This works, but I need to send various links to my friends, i.e. links to various files (file01, file02...) displayed automatically when the link is accessed.

So, is there a way to execute this js with various `id` parameter via url ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697559/call-js-function-via-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a hashtag to the url and use it as a file name.

```
http://your-url.com/somefile.php#file01
```

and then:

```
var file = window.location.hash;
//then you load your file via js
```

Comment: @Thanks, FakeHeal, I will try